# Insert date in mysql using php mysqli functions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this REST api code on backend:

```
public function createDay($user_id, $day, $startLocation, $startTime) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO days(day,startLocation,startTime,dayDate) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $day, $startLocation, $startTime, $dayDate);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if ($result) {
            // task row created
            // now assign the task to user
            $new_day_id = $this->conn->insert_id;
            $res = $this->createUserDay($user_id, $new_day_id, $dayDate);
            if ($res) {
                // task created successfully
                return $new_day_id;
            } else {
                // task failed to create
                return NULL;
            }
        } else {
            // task failed to create
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

and function createDay:

```
public function createUserDay($user_id, $day_id, $dayDate) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_days(user_id, day_id, $dayDate) values(?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("iis", $user_id, $day_id, $dayDate);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if (false === $result) {
            die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

this is dbhandler file, now i have a question -

I use

```
 $new_day_id = $this->conn->insert_id;
```

to get ID of current data but also how I can get `$dayDate` to use into `createUserDay` function

So I need to get $dayDate and use it into createUserDay function, is there any way?

Comment: What is your SQL? Are you using INT? Datetime? Timestamp?

Comment: I use just DATE type ... $datum = $app->request->post('startTime');
   $datum = ($datum / 1000);
   
   $startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datum);
   $dayDate = date("Y-m-d", $datum);